# How do i loop something a variable amount of times?

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I want to generate makeid what ever number they enter times

```
var rl = require("readline");
var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
prompts.question("How many codes would you like to generate? ", function (number) {
    function makeid(length) {
        var result = '';
        var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: You are asking how many ids to make, but you also need to know how long — where does `length` in `makeid(length)` come from?

Comment: Can't you just use a `for` loop that repeats `number` times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this?

```
const CODE_LENGTH=16; // or whatever - get it from somewhere...
var rl = require("readline");
var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
prompts.question("How many codes would you like to generate? ", function (number) {
    function makeid(length) {
        var result = '';
        var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return result;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<number; i++) {
      var code = makeid(CODE_LENGTH);
      console.log(code); // do whatever with the code...
    }
});
```

Comment: Now how would I make it save the codes to a file that the user specified from another prompts.question

Comment: New question infinity ;)

Comment: I have tried to use fs.appendFile and .writeFile but I can't get either to work. I cant make another question for 2 more days

Comment: General rule is, if you have new questions that arise after this one is resolved, please post a new question and mark this as answered.